# Calculating number of days between Admission Date and today

Tags: sql, datediff, coalesce

I found the following in Stackoverflow and have been working with it to find the number of Patient Days each month. It works very well if I have both the Admit and Discharge dates.

I can't figure out how to edit it to calculate the Patient days when the discharge date has not been completed... the patient is still in the hospital. If feels like I should use Coalesce or ISNULL to find the records where the Discharge Date is NULL, but I'm not a programmer and would appreciate your help.

```
WITH Mos AS (
  SELECT
  D.ED_ADMIT_DATE,
  D.ED_DISCHARGE_DATE,
  Number,

  DateAdd(Month, Number, D.ED_ADMIT_DATE - Day(D.ED_ADMIT_DATE) + 1) MoDate
 FROM
  cases_cstm D
  INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values V ON V.Number <= DateDiff(Month, D.ED_ADMIT_DATE,  D.ED_DISCHARGE_DATE)
WHERE
  V.Type = 'P'), Dys AS (
SELECT
  MoDate,
  DateDiff(
     Day,
     CASE WHEN Number = 0 THEN ED_ADMIT_DATE ELSE MoDate END,
     CASE WHEN Number = DateDiff(Month, ED_ADMIT_DATE, ED_DISCHARGE_DATE) THEN  ED_DISCHARGE_DATE ELSE DateAdd(Month, 1, MoDate) -1 
 END
  ) + 1 Cnt
FROM Mos)
 SELECT  Year(MoDate) Yr,
 Coalesce(DateName(Month, MoDate), 'Total') Mo,
 Convert(varchar(11), Sum(Cnt)) + ' day' + CASE WHEN Sum(Cnt) = 1 THEN '' ELSE 's' END Descr

FROM Dys
GROUP BY  MoDate
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY
Grouping(MoDate),
MoDate;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace each occurance of `ED_DISCHARGE_DATE` with:

```
IsNull(ED_DISCHARGE_DATE,getdate())
```

This uses the current time whenever the discharge date is unavailable.